# Required Field Validation on numbers with no decimals and "%" sign.

Tags: c#, forms, validation, .net

I am required to validate textbox on numbers with no decimals and percentage sign, e.g.

1% , 15% , 78%, 100%.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the string [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) function to remove the percent sign and then use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to integer to see if you have a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
var value = "10%".Trim('%');
int no;
if(tryParse(value, out no))
{
// Your code here


}
```